# Peer to peer connection using react-native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mobile-development

I am looking to build a Mobile app using react-native that should be able to find nearby phones with the same app installed. At a highlevel, I am looking for something like this:

1. This app should be able to send a kid of identifier (GUID) via Bluetooth (?) and also listen for signals from other devices in the proximity.
2. Identify the incoming GUID and calculate very rough distance (may be based on signal strength or something like that)

I am aware of privacy issues and battery issues with this approach. So any ideas into libraries or approaches to achieve the basic discovery will be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: have you managed to find a solution to your problem?